# General solution to linear differential equation with complex coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a homogeneuous, linear differential equation with constant **but complex** coefficients:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-(a+\boldsymbol{i}b)y=0, (1)$$ 
where  $\boldsymbol{i}$ is a imaginary unit.

I do know that if $\boldsymbol{i}$ is absent, i.e. $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-(a+b)y=0,$ it is just a homogeneuous, linear differential equation with constant coefficients, whose general solution is straightforward:

$$y=c_1e^{\sqrt{a+b}x}+c_2e^{-\sqrt{a+b}x}.$$

Any hint for the general solution to equation (1)?

Comment: I don't think there is anything that stops you from doing it using the usual method for real coefficients.

Comment: @CheeHan, thanks a lot. But the problem is that if there are complex coefficients in the characteristic equation, say, $r^n+a_1r^{n-1}+...+a_{n-1}r+a_n=0$. In this case, are there always $n$ (real) roots corresponding to the homogeneous fundamental solution?

Comment: There are always $n$ roots, but even for real polynomials, those roots are not always real ($r^2 + 1$ for example). And when the some of the coefficients are not real themselves, then at least one of the roots will not be a real number.